# Using testlink API Invalid DevKey Error message

Tags: python, api, xml-rpc, testlink

I am currently using Testlink 1.9.11 and I have difficulties to use the API for testlink. I searched on the web for similar issues but nothing helped.

Here are the scenario that I follow in order to try to use the API:

1. Log in as my user with admin rights)
2. Go to 'My settings' and under API interface, I click on 'Generate a new key' button (-> meaning that $tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE)
3. I have tried this Python code

   ```
   TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL="http://xxxxxxxx/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php"
    TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY=["xxxxxxxx"]

    import testlink
    tls =testlink.TestlinkAPIClient(TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL,TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY)

    print (tls.countProjects())
   ```

when I try to run python file it show me ==>

> raise testlinkerrors.TLResponseError(
> testlink.testlinkerrors.TLResponseError: 2000: Can not authenticate
> client: invalid developer key

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

```
Import testlink
from testlink import  TestLinkHelper

TestLinkHelper.DEFAULT_DEVKEY="http://xxxxxxxx/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php"
TestLinkHelper.DEFAULT_SERVER_URL=xxxxx"

tlsh = testlink.TestLinkHelper().connect(testlink.TestlinkAPIClient)

print (tlsh.countProjects() )
```